# FTPClient in android convert image to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, ftp, apache-commons-net

Help!!  i have installed ApacheCommons.net  FTPClient. As i need to download a PNG file via ftp.  The stream downloads but iam having trouble converting it into a Bitmap so i can save to local storage.

```
        mFTPClient.connect("path");
        mFTPClient.login("anonymous","nobody");
        mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/fax");
        InputStream inStream = mFTPClient.retrieveFileStream("nweimage.PNG");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF8");
```

Been trying to use BitmapFactory to convert it, but just keep getting null return.

Any pointers

Cheers

Comment: Why would you convert a png file to a Bitmap first? You are using a ftp component. The FTP protocol is for transferring files. So nothing easier than download the file to disk directly.

Comment: thanks, hadnt thought of that

Answer (score 0):

This is how i got around it. Thanks greenapps for making me think down a different route

```
     mFTPClient.connect("path");
        mFTPClient.login("anonymous","nobody");
        mFTPClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        mFTPClient.changeWorkingDirectory("/fax");
        mFTPClient.setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
        mFTPClient.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    try{
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

            boolean status = mFTPClient.retrieveFile("image.PNG", out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```